# Flex topLevelApplication and SuperTabNavigator mouse event handler

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, mouseevent

I am using the flex `SuperTabNavigator` and want on closing the tab check if the control button was pressed. I tried:

```
    public static var CONTROL_PRESSED:Boolean = false;

    public function init():void {
        var clickListener:Function =  function _clickListener(event:MouseEvent):void{
            trace(event.ctrlKey);
            if(event.ctrlKey){
                CONTROL_PRESSED = true;
            }else{
                CONTROL_PRESSED = false;
            }
        };

        FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickListener);

    }
```

The problem with this is that the mouse click is called everywhere in the application *except* on the tab. I also tried the same code but `addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickListener);` to add the listener to the `SuperTabNavigator` and it did not work at all. Is there another way to catch the mouse click?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `SuperTabNavigator` has a private mouse click handler function that hides the `MouseEvent`:

```
private function closeClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    if(this.enabled) {
        dispatchEvent(new Event(CLOSE_TAB_EVENT));
    }
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

You'll need to modify the `SuperTab` class in the `SuperTabNavigator` source to dispatch some `CustomEvent` with the data you want instead of a plain `new Event(CLOSE_TAB_EVENT)`.

Then change the `onCloseTabClicked` function in `SuperTabBar` to know about your `CustomEvent`.  Then you can pass that to your application code (by adding it to the `SuperTabEvent`, perhaps).